# Como posso rolar para um local específico na página usando jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível rolar para um local específico na página usando jQuery?

A localização que eu quero rolar precisa ter:

```
<a name="#123">here</a>
```

Ou pode simplesmente passar um ID DOM específico?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
$("#botao").on('click',function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $("#div_para_scrollar").position().top
    });
});
```